# Scheduled to Activation

Tags: aem

I am trying to get the pages which are scheduled to activated in cq5.5 through code.To get the pages ,which are activated,I have used the property replicationAction. 
But for the pages which are scheduled to activated,is there any similar property we can use or is there any other way we can get it.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

It's not trivial, but doable. I'm not sure whether that's the easiest way to achieve it, but this is how I'd start:

1. Get an [`AgentManager`](http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-0/develop/ref/javadoc/com/day/cq/replication/AgentManager.html) service through reference
2. Find the appropriate [`Agent`](http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-0/develop/ref/javadoc/com/day/cq/replication/Agent.html) from the map retrieved by `getAgents()`
3. `getQueue()` on the agent will give you the [`ReplicationQueue`](http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-0/develop/ref/javadoc/com/day/cq/replication/ReplicationQueue.html) object that provides the functionality you're looking for.